# Strikeout in different color appears behind letters, not on top of them

Tags: color, strikeout, ulem

When using package `ulem`'s strikeout facilities (macro `\sout`) and also color in my text, the strikethrough appears *behind* the letter string:

```
\documentclass{article} % I also often work with the memoir package (in case this matters for the range of possible fixes)
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % option normalem not needed for example but often loaded by me (mentioned for the unlikely case it matters for the fix)
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
Hello \textcolor{red}{\sout{\textcolor{black}{Welt }}}World!
\end{document}
```

(If I specify a different color combination, like green or magenta for the text, the effect persists - I just didn't want the compiled example to look ugly or unrealistic.)

How can I have strikethrough in a color different from the text appear *on top of* the text?

Comment: Using [`ulem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ulem) it seems like you're not concerned about line-breaking. Is this the case?

Comment: I was using `ulem` mainly because I like its underlining facilities (because its `\uline` doesn't increase the line spacing, which is what I usually want). Of course if anyone has other pointers to things that work and are compatible with many packages, I'll be glad to know. (That is, I never really thought about line-breaking. I am always glad about further insights.)

Comment: @werner why do you say that? -- ulem was the first underline package (iirc) that offered breakable underlines (etc.).  it's listed in the uk faq as a solution in a question "underlined text won't break"; there has never been a complaint about that answer, to the faq maintainers...

Comment: @wasteofspace: You're right. The construction in the MWE led me to believe otherwise. The nested use of `\textcolor` and `\sout` removes the line-breaking capability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `SOUL` package.  Linebreaks etc. are respected although spacing may change very slightly if prior experience holds true.  I tried with `ulem` but likely because of my unfamiliarity of the package, I couldn't get a solution that would work for more than a single word.  I'm not sure if the `SOUL` package is any less compatible than `ulem` when it comes to conflicts etc.

I believe that both packages first draw the line, and the place the text which is why the line is in the background.  There may be other ways around that problem, but my "soul"ution was to typeset zero-width text (using `\rlap`), and then strikeout a phantom version of the text on top of it.  The command takes two optional arguments: the first sets the color of the strike (default red) and the second sets the color of the text.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\sotwo}{O{red}O{black}+m}
    {%
        \begingroup
        \setulcolor{#1}%
        \setul{-.5ex}{.4pt}%
        \def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
            \rlap{%
                \color{#2}\the\SOUL@syllable
                \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern}%
            \SOUL@ulunderline{%
                \phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
        }%
        \ul{#3}%
        \endgroup
    }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello \sotwo{Welt} World!

\sotwo[green]{Here is a long sentence that will span across a number of lines to force a linebreak}

\sotwo[green][blue]{Here is a long sentence that will span across a number of lines to force a linebreak}

Here is a long sentence that will span across a number of lines to force a linebreak

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the example work with equally well with `color` instead of `xcolor`, or is the latter package strictly speaking necessary in some non-obvious way?

Comment: Oh, do you think you could add code so that I can also vary the color of the text?

Comment: It should work equally well with either `color` or `xcolor`.  I added a second optional argument for the color of the text.

Comment: The following works with `ulem` but not across line breaks because of the `phantom`: `\newcommand\reduline{\bgroup\markoverwith
{\textcolor{red}{\rule[0.5ex]{2pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\newcommand\topline[1]{\rlap{#1}\reduline{\phantom{#1}}}`

Comment: Just curious, how does the unmatched `\bgroup` work?

Comment: Buried in the `ulem` scanner (`\ULon`) is a matching `\egroup` that is inserted after the argument is read and dealt with.  Something like `\newcommand\mystuff[1]{do stuff\egroup}` which could then be used like `{\bgroup\mystuff{argument stuff}}`